# jenkins debugging with eclipse

Tags: jenkins

I have built a new "Hello World" plugin for Jenkins and I was able to upload it onto Jenkins and it works successfully. I am now trying to make change to the plugin and debug it on Jenkins. I did this according to the instructions on this tutorial https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial

I tried this command:

```
mvnDebug hpi:run
```

and then start to debug from eclipse to the port 8000 which is the port that Jenkins opens up for debugging. The eclipse was able to connect to the correct port and I got the message which seems to be correct:

```
[info] Jenkins is fully up and running
```

It seems that everything went OK. Then I go to localhost:8080 to see the plugin but I found nothing there. Can anybody help me with this, please? Thanks.

Comment: Same observation here. In my case I was trying to debug an existing plugin (vSphere-cloud-plugin). I even tried uploading the hpi file under my local target folder to my localhost:8080 Jenkins instance, but yet I don't see a link to add a new cloud on the Manage Jenkins URL.

Comment: Make sure you are checking on this url: http://localhost:8080/jenkins/ (with the '/jenkins/' at the rear).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, about debugging Jenkins plugins, I know that there is a little amount of information. I can tell you how I debug:

Using the tutorial from https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-DebuggingaPlugin 
1. stop jenkins service
2. from cmd I run 
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n
and
mvn hpi:run
Note: Build automatically must be unchecked in Eclipse. And after I run mvn hpi:run I try to connect Eclipse to the port using java remote ( or something like this).

The second method that I use is:
1. I installed maven plugin in eclipse
2. Create a run configuration as maven in eclipse 
3. Stop jenkins server
4. Run the configuration
5. Access localhost:8080/jenkins

Sorry for not giving the exact steps but I have those configurations on my PC at work...

Also, in my opinion the second method is more stable. I use it frequently when I work with my plugin...